# Removing, Searching, and Returning a position using Type T

Tags: java, generics, methods, types

Need help defining these methods, I am not familiar using Type T.

Define the following two methods in the `LinkedList` class:

1) The `searchItem` method takes an item to be search of type T in the list and if it is found then returns the position in the list, otherwise return -1

2) The `removeItem` method takes as argument an item to be removed of type T and returns true if the item is successfully removed, otherwise returns false.

Comment: Type T is like template you use in generic programming. It generally used in classes to substitute polymorphic behavior. Not applicable in your case.

Comment: This is not a drop off point for homework questions.

Comment: the generics just obfuscate that you're being asked to navigate through linked lists, like Maarten implied, a common first-year programmer home work assignment....

Answer (score 0):

This sounds suspiciously like homework.

When you create a generic class in java you just need the class to have the  on it.

```
public class LinkedList<T>
```

The T can be any letter you want it to be. It does not matter what you choose. Then when you create an instance of that class you will give it type t.

```
LinkedList<int> mylist = new LinkedList<int>();
```

This will create an instance of the linked list where everything that references T will be replaced with int.

So your methods just need to use type T.

```
public class LinkedList<T>
{

    public int Search(T toSearch)
    {
        //search your nodes
        return -1;
    }

    public boolean Remove(T toRemove)
    {
        //find item and remove if you can, return true
        return false;
    }

}
```

Just as a final note, returning a boolean for success is **BAD**. It is an exceptional case if the user tries to remove something that isn't in the list, and should throw an exception. Otherwise it does not need to return anything.